# MVC 5 Html.Action.Link open as toggle

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC so i want to ask. I made basic database with entity framework,everything is just fine. In index page i have generated stuff

```
<th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
```

etc...

Than i have 3 actionlinks to modify database.

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
```

Now my question is, can i somehow open actionlink so after click it will toggle below them rather than open in new page. Thanks for help. I think Jquery might be help but i have no idea how to use it.

Edit:

Tank you very much Harry. So ajax is the way :) i copied code you posted, changed to my controller name but it's not working. Button is there but doing nothing.

code:

```
<button type="button" class="editButton" data-id="@item.ID">Edit</button>
       <div id="content">               
       </div>
           <script>
               $(".editButton").click(function (){
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "/PacientsController/Edit?id=" + $(this).data("id"), success: function (result) {
                           $("#content").html(result);
                           }
                   });

               });
           </script>
```

Am I supposed to change more things than just controller? Or maybe i'm an idiot.

Comment: It seems you are looking for the behavior of a Tab component. Take a look at [Bootstrap Tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs) and [example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h)

Comment: You need to read up on partial views and ajax posts in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Try using Ajax.ActionLink instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily. ActionResult controllers return html so you can make the request using ajax and just drop the result into the html in the page.

```
<button type="button" class="editButton" data-id="@item.ID">
   Edit
</button>
<div id="content">

</div>
<script>
    $(".editButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/controllerName/Edit?id=" + $(this).data("id"), success: function (result) 
            {
                $("#content").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that I have used html5 data attributes to transfer the corresponding id and i have used unobtrusive class clicks in case you have more that one edit button on the page.